# How can I evaluate the intersection's volume of a circle and the area above a line. I also would like to apply it. - Python

Tags: python, numpy, random, area

This is using Python.

I tried to post an image, but failed... So it may be difficult to understand.

I call the intersection of a part inside a circle (of which center is (0, 0) and the radius is 1) and a part above a line (y = x).I call it yellow part.

I would like to evaluate the area of the yellow part with random numbers and without for statement or while statement, but I don't know how to do it.

Plus, I also apply it to 3-D.That is, the intersection of a part inside an ellipse (2x^2+3y^2+z^2-4=0) and a part above plane(x+y+2z-1=0). But this is an additional question. It would be easy to do it if I can do it in 2-D.

I'd like to calculate some of volumes in my experiment. I have tried some of my codes, but they don't work. 
I appreciate it if you would answer my question.

What I coded↓

```
import numpy as np
size = 10000

if y - x > 0:
    x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size)
    y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size)
area = x**2 + y**2
print(len(area[area < 1])/size)
```

The area of the yellow part would be expected from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the y-x > 0 conditional in the wrong place.

```
import numpy as np
size = 10000
# Generate random x and y in the square ((-1, -1) (1, 1))
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size)
area = x*x + y*y

# Move the y-x conditional into the boolean array.
print(len(area[np.logical_and(area < 1, (y-x)>0)])/size)
# The logical and of the points inside the circle and those where y>x.
0.3963
```

This gives you the proportion of points in the area you want to calculate.

Area of the square = 4.
The proportion both in the circle and gt y-x= 0 .3963
4*.3963 = 1.5852 which is close enough to the pi/2 expected.

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to identify the points in each set. [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) helps for that :

```
size=10000
x,y = 2*np.random.rand(2,size)-1 # random points in a square
circle= np.where( x*x+y*y<=1)

xc,yc=x[circle],y[circle]  # points in circle

half_circle = np.where(yc<xc)

xh,yh= xc[half_circle],yc[half_circle]  # points in half circle

from pylab import scatter

scatter(x,y,c='red')
scatter(xc,yc,c='blue')
scatter(xh,yh,c='yellow',s=1)
print(len(xh)/size)
#0.39441
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do it without for statement or while statement means you have to use NumPy vector capabilities. Here is the code, which samples uniformly in the unit circle, counts number of points above `y=x` line and prints area.

```
import numpy as np

N=100000 # number of trials

# sampling uniformly in the circle
angle  = 2.0 * np.pi * np.random.random(N)
radius = np.sqrt(np.random.random(N))

x = radius * np.cos(angle)
y = radius * np.sin(angle)

t = np.where(y > x)[0]

print(np.pi * len(t)/float(N))
```

It prints `1.5705135834560735` which is about π/2.